# Get column names from a matrix using a condition

Tags: r

I'm new in R and trying to figure out the language.

I have the following matrix:

```
               HRV Focus Tiguan Elantra
Price      20265.0 18175  24995 17250.0
Engine         1.8     1      2     1.8
Auto           1.0     0      1     0.0
Horsepower   141.0   123    200   145.0
```

**How can I get the column names from the cars that their price is bigger than 20000?**

In the specific question the answer should be: HRV, Tiguan

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `colnames(mydf)[mydf["Price", ] > 20000]` or something like that?

Comment: Conventionally one puts the cases in the rows and variables in the columns whereas the data shown has it the other way around.  Use transpose (`t`) to get the more conventional layout.  Then google for `subset rows R`

Comment: thank you for the answers.  A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 your answer works great for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is really a `matrix` and not a `data.frame` then:

```
 colnames(your_matrix)
```

Gives the column names - a character vector.

Since price is in the first row

```
your_matrix[1, ] > 20000
```

Gives a logical vector indicating the columns where the price is greater than 20000.

To get "column names from the cars that their price is bigger than 20000", just put those pieces together, using the logical test you want to subset the column names vector.

```
colnames(your_matrix)[your_matrix[1, ] > 20000]
```